# Name of the admin page login view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-login

My aim is to redirect the Users from the login page of the admin page in Django. The plan was to go for the login view and change the redirect direction to the template I'm aiming to use. But to be honest I don't know where to find that view. When you have cooler ideas on how to redirect from the login page to a custom template with a custom view please write it down :D Thank you for every help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) setting to redirect your user after they login. You won't be able to specify a particular view, only an URL string like `/foo/bar/`.

Comment: weirdly it doesn't work for me :/ I now edited the views in django/contrib/auth/views.py and changed the redirect url, but I think that's a bad method :D